# Limiting identical values in Parse query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse query that will return many objects of different keys and values. I want to limit the number of identical values returned by a particular key.

Let's say I'm querying a library of books. Assume I'm getting the `book` and `author` object keys. Is there any way to limit identical key-values? For instance, if I have 10 books authored by Hemingway, Twain, and Dickens each, can I limit the query to only return each of their first 5 books?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform one query on these three people in order to achieve it like so:

```
[query1 whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"Hemingway"];
query1.limit = 5;
[query1 findObjects]

[query2 whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"Twain"];
query2.limit = 5;
[query2 findObjects]

[query3 whereKey:@"author" equalTo:@"Dickens"];
query3.limit = 5;
[query3 findObjects];
```

Comment: What if I have hundreds of authors? I surely can't use that method. That's really what I need to find out.

Comment: You can try to use subquery as well. https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html has all the info.

Comment: Afraid I couldn't find anything related